Invalid Signature of JWT token validation in .NET [SOLVED]
I'm working on implementing JWT authentication for my ASP.NET Core application, but I’m encountering issues with token validation. Despite configuring the issuer and audience, I'm getting errors related to invalid signatures and issuer validation.
Token generation (Located within my AuthController):
private string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = _configuration["Jwt:Key"] ?? "<key>";
            var keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            var userRoles = _userService.GetIdentityRole(user).Result;

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email ?? string.Empty),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString())
            };

            claims.AddRange(userRoles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }

Token Validation Configuration (Located within Program.cs):
// Configure JWT Authentication
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<key>");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});

When testing the JWT token in jwt.io I get invalid signature.
I am unsure if there is any other configuration needed or if I have been missing a step for validating the JWT token?
Thanks
EDIT
After some debugging I received this in my console:
Authentication failed: IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).
The token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.
Here is an example of a generated token:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InNpbW9uLnNqb28yMUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJuYW1laWQiOiJkYzhkOTRjZS1hMDBhLTQ5ZTUtOTMzNS0wYzMyY2E1MGRmYjciLCJyb2xlIjoiUmVnaXN0ZXJlZCIsIm5iZiI6MTcyNTYzMzI2NCwiZXhwIjoxNzI1NjM2ODY0LCJpYXQiOjE3MjU2MzMyNjR9.IxmR4FiakEeFjJz6KYRrUNtK2Cqf0gh_C88WRf_MoA4
[SOLVED]
After a lot of digging, I found another post with someone that had the same issue. It appears that "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" is causing the errors I have been getting above. Simply removing this package solved the issue!

This one at least I think is wrong: SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature. I've only used SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256 in the past.

Still not working sadly, it's first time for me working with this. Been debugging as much as I can but only receive "invalid_token" on Thunder Client, and JWT.io just say its invalid signature. @juunas - Hopefully I find a fix soon!

Crazy, but removing the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens worked, even though it is also an indirect dependency for other packages.  Had to remove it from the project that had a direct dependency to it.  Maybe make this solution as an answer and accept it so we can upvote it for others to see.

The following code / class generates a JWT and validates it.  Perhaps you can copy some of the code for your specific use case - hope it helps:
Note - updated for .Net 8.0 (previous code was for .Net Framework 4.6.2):
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Text;

/*

   NUGET PACKAGES USED:
   
      System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

   NOTES:

      JWT must be transferred over HTTPs if you store any sensitive information in claims.

*/
namespace jwt_demo
{

   public class jwt
   {

      private readonly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey m_jwt_signing_key;

      private readonly System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler m_token_handler;


      // Constructor ...

      public jwt( String private_secret_key )
      {

         // Create signing key from our private secret key ...

         m_jwt_signing_key = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( private_secret_key ) );

         // Create token handler ...

         m_token_handler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

      }

      /*
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      Create a JWT and return it as a JSON string.

      PARAMETERS:

         None.

      RETURNS:

         A string that contains a JWT.

      ------------------------------------------------------------
      */

      public String create()
      {

         Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials credentials;

         System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken jwt;

         System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> claims;

         String jwt_str;


         // Create signing credentials ...

         credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials( m_jwt_signing_key, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature );


         // Create claims - information about the user or any other information you need - basicaly key/value pairs ...

         claims = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>();

         claims.Add( new System.Security.Claims.Claim( "user_id", "test_user_id" ) );

         claims.Add( new System.Security.Claims.Claim( "session_id", "test_session_id" ) );


         // Create token ...

         jwt = new JwtSecurityToken( issuer: null,
                                     audience: null,
                                     claims: claims,
                                     notBefore: null,
                                     expires: null,
                                     signingCredentials: credentials
                                   );

         // Serialize the token ...

         jwt_str = m_token_handler.WriteToken( jwt );

         return jwt_str;

      }


      /*
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      Returns true if the supplied JWT string is valid, false
      otherwise.

      ------------------------------------------------------------
      */
      public Boolean is_valid( String jwt_str )
      {

         Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken validated_token;

         Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters token_validation_params;

         System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal claims_principal;


         // A JWT token is required ...

         if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( jwt_str ) )
         {

            return false;

         }


         // Determine if the string is a well formed JWT ...

         if ( !m_token_handler.CanReadToken( jwt_str ) )
         {

            return false;

         }

         // Attempt to validate the token ...

         try
         {

            token_validation_params = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters();

            token_validation_params.ValidateActor = false;

            token_validation_params.ValidateAudience = false;

            token_validation_params.ValidateIssuer = false;

            token_validation_params.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;

            token_validation_params.IssuerSigningKey = m_jwt_signing_key;

            token_validation_params.ValidateLifetime = false;

            token_validation_params.ValidateTokenReplay = false;


            claims_principal = m_token_handler.ValidateToken( jwt_str, token_validation_params, out validated_token );

         }
         catch ( Exception ex )
         {

            Console.WriteLine( "EXCEPITON: " + ex.ToString() );

            return false;

         }


         // All tests passed ...

         return true;

      }


      /*
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      Returns true if the supplied JWT string is valid.  Also 
      return a SecurityToken if valid, null otherwise.

      ------------------------------------------------------------
      */
      public Boolean is_valid( String jwt_str, out Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken? validated_token )
      {

         Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters token_validation_params;

         System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal claims_principal;


         // Init ...

         validated_token = null;


         // Determine if the string is a well formed JWT ...

         if ( !m_token_handler.CanReadToken( jwt_str ) )
         {

            return false;

         }

         // Attempt to validate the token ...

         try
         {

            token_validation_params = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters();

            token_validation_params.ValidateActor = false;

            token_validation_params.ValidateAudience = false;

            token_validation_params.ValidateIssuer = false;

            token_validation_params.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;

            token_validation_params.IssuerSigningKey = m_jwt_signing_key;

            token_validation_params.ValidateLifetime = false;

            token_validation_params.ValidateTokenReplay = false;


            claims_principal = m_token_handler.ValidateToken( jwt_str, token_validation_params, out validated_token );

         }
         catch ( Exception ex )
         {

            Console.WriteLine( "EXCEPITON: " + ex.ToString() );

            return false;

         }


         // All tests passed ...

         return true;

      }

   }



   class Program
   {

      /*
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      Prompt to exit
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      */
      private static void prompt_to_exit()
      {

         Console.WriteLine( "----------" );

         Console.WriteLine( "Press Enter to exit:" );

         Console.ReadLine();

      }


      /*
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      ------------------------------------------------------------
      */
      static void Main( string[] args )
      {

         /*
         Our private secret key - NOT shared with anyone ...
         This key should be loaded via an environment variable / config file rather than being hard-coded.
         The key below was generated using: https://mkjwk.org/  (Key Size = 256, Key Use = Signing, Algorithm = HS256) ...
         */

         String private_secret_key = "DNCJwKRiCE3GA1pgqbwwmL12yOEN2l7oGl9PwRmptlM";


         Boolean ok;

         String? jwt_str;

         Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken? validated_token;

         jwt jwt_obj;



         jwt_obj = new jwt( private_secret_key );


         // Get a JWT (as a string) ...

         jwt_str = jwt_obj.create();

         Console.WriteLine( jwt_str );


         // Check if valid ...

         ok = jwt_obj.is_valid( jwt_str );

         if ( ok )
         {

            Console.WriteLine( "JWT is valid" );

         }
         else
         {

            Console.WriteLine( "JWT is NOT valid" );

         }


         // Check if valid - returns validated token ...

         ok = jwt_obj.is_valid( jwt_str, out validated_token );

         if ( ok )
         {

            Console.WriteLine( "JWT is valid" );

         }
         else
         {

            Console.WriteLine( "JWT is NOT valid" );

         }

#if DEBUG
         prompt_to_exit();
#endif

      }

   }

}


Hmm, I see. So, instead of relying on the automatic JWT validation that happens within my Program.cs (using middleware like JwtBearer), I can create a custom class to manually validate the token during each request. This class would handle the token validation process whenever a request is made, instead of the middleware doing it automatically?

You can do either! - the sample code was meant to provide an example of creating a JWT and validating it.   Hope that helps.

After my test, I reproduced your problem and found a solution. The reason for the problem is that during the JWT verification process, a signing key is required to ensure that the same key is used when generating and verifying JWT to ensure the integrity and authenticity of the token.
If the signing key of the JWT token is not configured during verification, this error will occur.

Therefore, it is necessary to add relevant configurations during verification, such as:
 IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
When Validate Issuer or Audience is set to false, it means that the Issuer and Audience of the token are not checked when verifying JWT. When it is set to true, it means checking whether the JWT comes from a specific issuer or is applicable to a specific audience. Then the Issuer and Audience fields in the token must match the verification parameters. The following is a complete example for your reference:
program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});

Appsettings:
 "Jwt": {
   "Key": "supersecretkeythatshouldbereplacedwithyourrealkey12345", 
   "Issuer": "https://localhost:8888", 
   "Audience": "https://localhost:7159" 
 },

GenerateJwtToken method:
public string GenerateJwtToken(string name)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = _configuration["Jwt:Key"] ?? "<key>";
    var keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name ?? string.Empty),
    };

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        Issuer= _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        Audience= _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}

When I get the token to access the authorized method, we can see that it can be verified through:


Hey! Thanks for the well informed answer. Unfortunately though, it did not solve the issue. Still getting these error messages in my terminal:
Authentication failed: IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).
Authentication failed: IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.). The token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.

If there is any other parts of my code I could share to resolve this issue, please let me know!
